# How to get Username from DB Based on Email posted in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a function named check() and posted email/password to the check() function from a login form. I want to get the username from the database based on this email address. The function is inside my controller as I am using the Query builder method.

```
public function check(Request $request){
    $user = DB::Table('users')->where('email',$request['email'])->get();
    return $users->username;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $user is array. Try first() instead get(). `$user = DB::Table('users')->where('email',$request['email'])->first();`

Comment: Yes, $user is an array. I was just confused about getting just username. Thanks for your response. It worked!!

Answer (score 0):

How about `$user = DB::Table('users')->where('email',$request['email'])->value('username');`? I think it is more accurate.